# Ajax call returning JSON forces IE8 and 7 to download file instead of reading it

Tags: ajax

I have a Drupal 7 site and I'm having [this issue, commented here for Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/952220)

The thing is that, when ajax response is set as *Content-Type: **text/javascript**; charset=utf-8* IE 7 and 8 try to download the file. The solution they propose is to change a line in common.inc to declare the response as *Content-Type: **text/html**; charset=utf-8*

The solution they propose there means I have to modify Drupal core, I would prefer not to do that as this will be a problem in future Drupal updates.

So, have any of you found this problem? do you know another solution?

PS: When I enter my site, I also find a javascript error in consle saying *JQuery is not defined* in a lina of drupal.js where it does *jQuery.noConflict(); // Allow other JavaScript libraries to use $.* I don't think it's related but comment it just in case...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally located the error: it was because of the file codification, some of them were in *UTF-8* and other ones in *UTF-8 without BOM* so IE7 detected an strange character at the beginning of the json being unable to parse it, coding all files *(js* files, *php* and module files) in *UTF-8 without BOM* solved the problem

Comment: BOM also causes problems with the minification that Drupal uses, especially CSS.